# "Border protection" vs "boarder protection"

Tags: terminology

Is the term *boarder protection* valid? It has 52,500 results on Google. What is the difference between *boarder protection* and *border protection*?

Comment: This is either "not a real question" or "general reference".

Comment: Hey, dude!  A **boarder** is someone who spends all day doing the skateboard thing...  The only protection they need is maybe from the sun in the summer.  Or the property owners who cite them for trespassing.

Comment: @GEdgar: Or, more seriously, a helmet, gloves, knee pads, etc.  It's not inconceivable that some of the hits referred to such equipment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A **border** is an edge or a boundary. A **boarder** is a tenant. Either one can be protected, so both are valid terms, although they mean different things.

If you look through the Google results for "boarder protection" (it initially corrects and shows results for "border protection"), you will see that most occurrences are misspellings or typos. There is [one](http://www.commerce.wa.gov.au/consumerprotection/content/Property_renting/Renting_and_tenancy/Tenants/Boarders_and_lodgers.html), however, that refers to boarders and lodgers in the context of consumer protection.

Answer (score 4):

I just typed 'boarder protection' into google and it gave me the results for 'border protection'. It also had a small link to click on for results for 'boarder protection' instead but the point is that when I typed in 'boarder protection' it gave me the results for 'border protection' because 'border protection' is the correct way to write the term that refers to preservation of a country's frontiers.

You can click on 'boarder protection' but if you look at the results you will find that they relate to 'boarders' (like those who reside at school because perhaps they live too far away to commute daily) OR they do relate to 'border security' but 'border' was misspelt as 'boarder'. Where the results for 'boarder protection' relate to boarders, you will find that there is probably just the word 'protection' or something on the same page. In short, 'boarder protection' is not a term in the sense that 'border protection' is a term.

I wouldn't read too much into 'boarder protection'.

Answer (score 3):

One would be protecting your country's borders from invading armies

The other would be protecting the students that stay at the school overnight.

Comment: Looking at the results in Google, both terms seem to be related to homeland security.

Comment: Then either the DHS has a special taskforce to guard the students at elite public(UK)/private(US) schools - or they are illiterate.

Answer (score 3):

I´d dare say all those google hits were just *typos* :)